# How to call a method in WPF application from a WCF Service hosted by the same WPF application?

Tags: wpf, wcf

I've created a WCF service that is hosted in a WPF application. Everything works. My clients can access the WCF service without issue.

Now, when a client call a method in my service, eg: SetData(MyDataObject data), I want that method to send the "data" object back to the WPF host for processing.

How would I wire that up???

**My Service hosted in WPF App:**

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFTestService.Service1), new Uri("http://localhost:8733/WCFTestService/"));

// Service host is opened on the UI thread
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WCFTestService.IService1), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");

// Enable metadata exchange
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior() { HttpGetEnabled = true };
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

// Enable exeption details
ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
sdb.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

host.Open();
```

**My WCF Service Method:**

```
public bool SetData(MyDataObject data)
{
   //HOW DO I get MyDataObject to the WPF Host???
   // something like: host.UpdateData(data) <-- callback method???
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am digressing from the question, but is there a particular reason that the presentation layer and the service layer are coupled so closely? I think you could add the contents of MyDataObject to a data transfer object you create, or persist MyDataObject (maybe temporarily) and then have the WPF application/host access it through a method call exposed by the same wcf service. I would probably do it that way, with the data you have provided.